# Display major version of all documents by default

Tags: document-library

We have many document library which you we use for Document Management System. These documents are also being called from a custom navigation system.

The issue is:

When an author or approver access the documents through navigation system, he can open the minor or unpublished version.

Is there a way that i can filter and show only published versions by default in document library list view and approver/editors will have some mechanism to change views to get access to minor/draft version.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is something impossible using the default features. That behavior is the one that SharePoint support, and the reason behind lies on what is an approver. SharePoint shows minor versions to contributors and owners. In addition, approvers are roles between these two so, we can think of an approver like a person with more rights than a contributor.

Let's say the approver search for a document, in the results page she will see the latest document, I mean, the latest minor version of this document. This is something really important you have to deal with your solution.

However, in on-premises farms or at least in 2013 farms, you can implement custom webparts to show latest major versions and the proper url using the SharePoint object model. I don't know if online supports it.

Hope this can bring some light to this matter.

Answer (score 0):

> Since the Published and Draft documents have the format:
>
> {MajorVersionNumber}.0 for Published
>
> {MajorVersionNumber}.{MinorVersionNumber} for Drafts

Use `[Version] CONTAINS .0` to show only published versions. Source: [Draft version visibility](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/75783/draft-version-visibility)

Comment: this will completely filter out the documents having minor versions. What i really want is to always shows published or major version for each document to everyone irrespective of their permissions & document version. E.g there's a user 'X' who's author and a second user 'Y' who's a reader. Let's say there are two documents in the library  with version 1.2 and 3.5. Following is the SP default functionality. The reader will see version as 1.0 and 3.0 for both documents whereas the author will see 1.2. and 3.5. I would also like author to see ver 1.0 and 3.0 by default. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

```
/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/Shared Documents/filename.docx')/versions
```

Gets a value that returns a collection of file version objects that represent the versions of the file.